# Logotipo do SOpt de casamento igualitário

Tags: debate, design

Agora de manhã acabei de entrar no SOen e me deparei com o logo colorido, acompanhando clima *gay pride*.
O melhor é a frase **"Marry whomever you love. Even if they're not a developer."**
O Github, ThoughtWorks, Bitbucket além de Facebook, Twitter e etc.  também acompanharam.
 Por que não aqui no SOpt também?

Comment: Relevante para o assunto: [Can Stack Overflow and Meta's logos be changed temporarily to the “#LoveOverflows” logo?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297859/1964435)

Comment: "I'm the CEO, co-founder, and inventor of Stack Overflow. I'm gay, American, and married, and have taken a lot of crap over the years for all three of those things, so this is a big day for me." Wow

Comment: Vai para ali uma discussão...

Comment: Não gosto de responder perguntas com outras perguntas (sim, eu via Chaves.), mas porque aderirmos tal movimento ? [espero que isso não vá para o lado errado.]

Comment: @emanuelsn Principalmente para demonstrar apoio, como desenvolvedores o nosso trabalho não deve se limitar apenas as questões técnicas mas também sociais. Toda a comunidade, entenda pelas grandes companhias da área, demonstraram o apoio. O próprio Stack Exchange já compartilhou a imagem e há apoio do CEO, não há motivos de a comunidade Português não aderir

Comment: Eu já discordo aderir, porque eu acredito que é algo que fica restrito a um movimento social que não pertence nem ao Brasil, nem à Portugal e nem a nenhum país de língua portuguesa. Se fosse o caso de ser relacionado a um desses países, concordaria plenamente.

Comment: Há uma representatividade do ato, foi autorizado na maior potência e é inegável, queiramos ou não, isto é uma influência para outros países. Especialmente para aqueles países, que pasmem ainda condenam como prática ilegal e pena de morte.

Comment: Complementando: Esse ato é especialmente essencial no Brasil pelo momento conservador que passamos, onde ainda se discute que a definição de "família" é formada por um casal heterossexual e filhos.

Comment: Mas a união estável por aqui, entre pessoas do mesmo sexo é permitida desde 2013. Salvo isso, muito possivelmente ainda se tem o mesmo tipo de filosofia conservadora em estados como Texas, por exemplo. Como eu disse, foi um passo muito importante pros EUA, mas não acho que seja motivo para outros países celebrarem. Os países devem celebrar suas próprias mudanças... Enfim, essa é só minha opinião

Comment: @Daniela Meu ponto de vista é bem parecido com o do Felipe. Não vejo motivos para isso. No BR isso já está assegurado a um tempom

Comment: By the way, o SOen já voltou ao logo normal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A logo foi alterada por conta da decisão da suprema corte dos EUA, que legaliza o casamento de mesmo sexo em todo o país. É uma enorme vitória pra comunidade LGBT que nós da empresa comemoramos, e mudamos a cor da logo em homenagem.

Apesar de um fato absolutamente notável, é algo que afeta exclusivamente pessoas que moram nos EUA. O casamento homoafetivo já estava em vigor desde 2013 no Brasil e 2010 em Portugal (apesar de ainda proibir a adoção), fora todos os outros países lusófonos que eu não sei como é a situação.

A notícia é excelente, mas não afeta nossa comunidade. Pode-se argumentar que o SOen é um site internacional, mas a grande maioria dos participantes é dos EUA, então é um assunto relevante lá.

Answer (score 7):

*Apenas minha opinião*

Eu não entendo sobre está causa e nem sei o impacto real dela para as comunidades do SE, o que eu entendi (eu acho que entendi) é o lado da *empresa StackExchange*, assim como qualquer empresa eles podem querer "melhorar" a imagem deles apoiando causas sociais e o *StackOverflow.com* sem sombra de duvidas é a maior comunidade do SE um bom lugar para fazer isto.

Então independente da causa, empresas fazem isto, apoiam seus "clientes" (aqui no caso usuários). Amanhã eles podem apoiar outras causas.

Eu não estou dizendo que a SE está *puxando o saco* destas causas, apenas estou dizendo que eles estão apoiando quem os apoia.

### O porque de não ter isto no SOpt

Temos *144 sites/comunidades* que são administrados por equipes menores (às vezes de uma pessoa) e que provavelmente precisam de aprovação em mudanças de algo que representa a empresa, como é o caso do logotipo, não é que o *SOpt* não quer apoiar a tal causa, apenas temos que levar em consideração que existe um processo burocrático para fazer mudanças no *layout*.

Se você abrir qualquer outro site da SE, vai notar que eles também não mudaram os seus logotipos, veja o http://superuser.com é o segundo maior site da SE e o logotipo deles não foi modificado.

---

### Outras causas importantes

Espero que no futuro apoiem outras causas, como a do suporte de TI (IT) e dos programadores.

### "Nós não arrumamos ar-condicionado!!! Exigimos respeito"

<sub>(ou cafeteiras, encanamento, lâmpadas, hackear facebook, etc)</sub>

<sub>- Desculpem o senso de humor</sub>

Comment: só faltou o hackear facebook :)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro kk adicionei

Comment: Ou quem sabe causas mais importantes ainda, que afetam muito mais pessoas de forma muito mais profunda. Eu apoio esta causa 100% mas me impressiona como as pessoas não se engajam em problemas da humanidade que são tão maiores.

Comment: @bigown é você tem toda razão, infelizmente a humanidade é assim.